# Exclude one factor level interaction calculation in lme4

Tags: r, model, interaction, r-factor, mixed

I am making mixed models, using `lme4`, which included three factors (S,M,R) with 2,3 and 4 levels. But I am missing observations for S3:M2:R1, so I am not able to check for the 3-way interaction.

Is there any way to tell `lme4` to ignore estimating a parameter for this level?

Instead of it giving me the message: `Error in mer_finalize(ans) : Downdated X'X is not positive definite, 21.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct the interaction variable by hand, and drop levels.  It would be nice if you gave a reproducible example, but:

```
mydata <- transform(mydata,SMRint=interaction(S,M,R,drop=TRUE))
lmer(response~SMRint+(1|grpvar),data=mydata)
```

Comment: Or `interaction(S, M, R, drop = T)`